# "SHOW TABLES" command returning tables not in the schema

Tags: mysql, backup, mysql-5.6

I was debugging a backup script at work and noticed that for some of our bigger tables (greater than 5GB), I'm noticing an odd discrepancy. If I run the command

```
mysql -h $host -u $user -p $pass -e 'show tables' $schema
```

I end up getting back something like

```
sales
sales_1
transaction
transaction_1
etc...
```

If I search for the tables with _1 using any MySQL client, they don't exist. The backup script is able to dump these tables just fine, but what are they for? More importantly, is there any reason I should take backups of them or is it safe to just exclude them?

This is occurring on Ubuntu 15.10 using MySQL 5.6 Community Edition.

Comment: Check by executing `select table_name, table_schema from information_schema.tables where table_name like '%\_1';`

Comment: Interesting. I modified that command slightly, turns out the tables with an underscore were views that are no longer used. Thanks for your help!